# Is it possible to use the free Wi-Fi at the Delhi Airport when one cannot receive a text message?

Tags: airports, india, wifi, new-delhi, del

Is it possible to use the free Wi-Fi at the [Delhi Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indira_Gandhi_International_Airport) when one cannot receive a text message?

The Wi-Fi network I found seemed to ask for OTP, which is sent by text message.

Comment: Are you sure that you cannot receive text messages? (often such messages are free). Sometime the authentication can be done with email (so you will have few minutes free internet to check email and get the code)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi if I could get a few minutes of free WiFi, then yes I could access my text messages. But I don't know if it's possible to get a few minutes of free WiFi over there. My best solution so far was to find someone willing to give me his phone number and receive the OTP for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was not able to use it when I tried.

They only accepted/processed Indian phone numbers, so when you have a phone from another country, (their) SMS don't work, and therefore you cannot connect. In my eyes, that is a rather silly limitation in an international airport.

Also, it seems by giving your phone number to use the wi-fi, you agree to 'receive advertisements'.
Friends who gave their Indian phone number get now flooded with spam since months, so maybe it's a good thing I wasn't able too.

Comment: I used it via a UK phone a few years ago without problems or junk calls.  However, things may have changed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an Indian and I'll give you a quick fix for this.
I was at IGI Airport (Delhi) few months back and a foreigner sitting right beside me was perplexed about how to use the free Wi-Fi he was in the same situation as you.

So what he did was:
He approached me politely and explained me his plight and since I had 2 sim registered in India (with different cellular companies) I happily agreed to help him. He just needed an OTP (One Time Password) via SMS to use the Wi-Fi and I helped.

So next time just approach any youngster (Yes this is important, no offence to fellow Indians but the older generation is bit rigid when it comes to lending a helping hand in anything that deals with technology) and explain your situation and ask for help. Usually most Indian youngsters carry 2 sim cards { Don't ask why, I have no reason. Maybe we can that's why ;) }

Enjoy next time you visit India. Cheers. :)